# Can't install charlock holmes gem, libicu-devel installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fedora, gitlab

I am trying to install charlock holmes, nevertheless, I keep getting an error:

```
[root@hugovm gitlab]# gem install charlock_holmes --version '0.6.9.4'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing charlock_holmes:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -licui18n... yes
checking for main() in -licui18n... yes
checking for unicode/ucnv.h... yes
  -- tar zxvf file-5.08.tar.gz
  -- ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/share/gems/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/ --disable-shared --enable-static --with-pic
  -- patch -p0 < ../file-soft-check.patch
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-icu-dir
    --without-icu-dir
    --with-icu-include
    --without-icu-include=${icu-dir}/include
    --with-icu-lib
    --without-icu-lib=${icu-dir}/
    --with-icui18nlib
    --without-icui18nlib
    --with-icui18nlib
    --without-icui18nlib
extconf.rb:7:in `sys': patch -p0 < ../file-soft-check.patch failed, please report issue on http://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes (RuntimeError)
    from extconf.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:59:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:59:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:55:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:55:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/share/gems/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/gem_make.out
```

I already installed libicu-devel.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same issue today. Tried to install gitlab on a clean fedora machine.
For me, a line in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/gem_make.out pointed to mkmf.log, which is in the same directory as above log file.

There it said "patch: command not found"

> sudo yum install patch

Answer (score 2):

In you output I can read:

> extconf.rb:7:in `sys': patch -p0 < ../file-soft-check.patch failed, **please report issue on http://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes** (RuntimeError)

So it all points to a bug. I suppose it is a good idea follow the output and created an issue there, explaining what you are trying to do and giving details of your environment.

Answer (score 2):

ruby-devel is missing

```
yum install ruby-devel
```

and you'll be set :)

Comment: Ok, I see your point, I didn't notice he was running this as root. Even running this with sudo, it wouldn't change the fact that he may lack the ruby-devel package. So to get this right, my answer got -1 because of sudo?

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the part with ruby-devel. Thought the whole point of your answer is the `sudo`. Had to edit your answer in order to revert the downvote.

Comment: What version of Fedora do you have? In f19 with ruby 2.0, I didn't encounter any problem. You could also try and install `rubygem-charlock_holmes` from the official repos if you use Fedora 19+. I maintain it.